# ASP.Net User Control Java Script function does not run

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have the function put here like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     UserControlNameInit();
});
```

The script are put in the following and the block is in the .ascx page.

`<script type="text/javascript">
</script>`

However, the function UserControlNameInit() does not run when the page loads. It is showing in the page source. I can still call this function through FireBug console by manually typing the name of the function.

I did the same way with other user controls, and it works. Just 1-3 user controls are not working...

Any possible reason for this? Thanks!

Comment: You should post the actual code.

Comment: have u added <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'> before your javascript function call?

Comment: @Pointy sorry for the simplicity, the actual user control is working before and I didn't change anything. I added two new user control to the page and it doesn't work. I am pretty sure it is the other user control leading to the problem.
@rahim thank you for reply, I have that added before the call. I edit the page.

Comment: @rahim that's not necessary - just plain `<script>` is all you really need.

Comment: @Zhao Until you post the Javascript code that's not working (and the other stuff you've recently added), nobody is going to know what the problem is.

Comment: thanks Pointy, you are right. It is just I am not sure sure which code actually caused the problem. it is a lot javascript code(like 500 lines) in the page. So I was hesitating to post the code to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. Thanks to IE 9 Beta's developer tool, which actually allow me to debug it and I saw script exception when the page loads and the problem is because of the newly added user control render html in correctly and block the functions call in the old user control. After I comment out the other user controls in the pages, the problem is gone. Now I need to figure out which control actually cause the problem.

Update: I think I found the right answer for this problem: I have initialization code written as below:

```
$(document).ready()
{
     UserControlNameInit();
}
```

Which blocks the call in the other user control which is written as this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    UserControlNameInit(); 
});
```

Although I don't know the difference between these too. But the later code seems to cause no problem to other user controls.

Thank you for all the attention and help.